# Thunderbird didn't got the structure of folders in my mail

Tags: thunderbird, email, gmail

I’ve installed Ubuntu 14.04 and configured Thunderbird for my mail. My problem is Thunderbird didn't got the structure of the folders in my mail. Thunderbird got all the mails in the Inbox folder.

Note: I'm using Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't have folders, but labels. Labels can be subscribed to in Thunderbird as folders this way:

1. Right-click on your Gmail Inbox folder (or any other Gmail folder)
2. Open Subscribe...
3. Choose the folders you want to subscribe to.

More info about Thunderbird+Gmail: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail